# What is a feasible way to measure water level in a pool skimmer?

Tags: sensing, level

I need to implement a wireless autofill system for a pool.  The skimmer is the only place that I can install the sensor (nine inches in diameter, made of ABS). When the pool is full it is 2" from the top, and when it needs refilling it is 6 inches from the top.  It is a hostile chemical environment (water, salt, chlorine). I tried mechanical floats, but they soon clog and stick. I have not been able to find a waterproof ultrasonic sensor with appropriate resolution. Has anyone had success with any contactless approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: It seems like a pressure sensor would work. I guess there may not be wireless versions, though.

Comment: But there could be some issues here. My skimmer level is not always the same as the pool level. If the skimmer gets blocked off or something, the level in the skimmer can go down quite a bit and the pump can even suck air. This would make the pool "look" empty and the autofill might start overflowing the level. Just something to think about.

Comment: Could condition the ‘fill’ (low) level measurement on whether the pump is running or not. Then, bonus: you’d know if the skimmer  is clogged if it went into ‘fill’ when the pump started.

Comment: How about a mechanical float, but build a cofferdam around it so it doesn't get clogged or jammed.  You could also/alternately have a very tight mesh filter around it, only water needs to pass through right?  And it really doesn't have to pass through super-quick --- Pools don't fill or drain all that fast.

Answer (score 4):

An optical fluid sensor would work. These use an LED/photo transistor pair in a plastic housing with a prism on one side. They’re popular in the aquarium trade but can be used for any fluid. Cheap, cheerful, simple to use.

You would use two, one for the ‘fill’ point and one for ‘stop’. They could be installed in the side of the skimmer housing, or in a dip tube attached to it.

In fact, if your skimmer has a cover, then maybe attach the dip tube with sensors plus a solar-powered wireless controller gizmo to the cover. (Product idea?)

More here: https://www.electroschematics.com/optical-liquid-level-sensor/

Another idea: optical time-of-flight sensor, again embedded in the skimmer cover. ST video about these things: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yytfrtn2pmc

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was unaware of this approach, and this looks promising.  I appreciate the useful links.  I am going to try mounting these on an acrylic strip and see if it works out.  With regard to a wireless controller, do you have any recommendations for an approach?  There is a strong WifFi signal at the location, so I was considering something like an ESP32 that wakes up once a day and transmits the status to a remote controller.

Comment: LoRa might be more suitable.